# Unable to remove files from directory

Tags: linux, perl

I am using **rm** to delete some files from a directory through a Perl script but it throws the error
 `can't exec "rm" no such file or directory`.

Command goes like this :

```
system("rm $directory$files"); $directory$files = /var/spool/mqueue/qf*
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has a builtin function for removing files, [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html). The third example shows how to use it in combination with [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to delete a list of files:

```
unlink glob "*.bak";
```

or in your case,

```
unlink glob($directory.$files);
```